# Organizing Objective-C code into submodules? Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, git, cocoapods

We're working on a small SDK.  We have all the code in one single project inside a workspace.  We want to refactor it out to create different submodules that can be later re-used.
Let's think of our SDK as something like TestFlight/FlightPath with submodules for Analytics, Logging, User Feedback, etc.

Ideally, we'd have a git repo with the Analytics isolated and a simple API that the SDK can use, same would apply for the other components.  This is great for unit testing, version management, etc.

We tried using cocoapods, but the problem that we found is that a static library cannot be linked to another static library, or at least there is not an easy/automated way of doing it. (If we are wrong, please correct us).

We could still try to use cocoapods just to bring the code (header & implementation files) to the same worskpace and then somehow have a script to copy them to the correct project and link them to it (this sounds like re-doing git submodules).

Is there anything to help with version/dependency management between static libraries in Objective-C?
Is there anything to facilitate the process?

Ideally we want to end up with something like the following where everything is a library OR an isolated module that can be re-used:

```
SDK
   Analytics
      Logging
   UserFeedback
      Logging
   SubcomponentA
   SubcomponentB
      Logging
   SubcomponentC
```

**Update**

When we tried to use cocoapods, we had something like this for our Podfile on our main workspace:

```
# workspace 'MyWorkspace/MyWorkspace.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '7.0'
xcodeproj 'MyWorkspace/MySDK/MySDK.xcodeproj'

target 'MySDK' do
    xcodeproj 'MyWorkspace/MySDK/MySDK.xcodeproj'

    pod 'Analytics', '0.0.1'
end
```

where `MyWorkspace` is an already existing workspace with different projects in it (all in the same directory), `MySDK` is the final product (a static library) and `Analytics` is one of the components living in its own *private* repository. So cocoapods was trying to link the `Analytics` static library against the `MySQK` static library(?)

We had this in our private specs repo (`PodSpecs/Analytics/0.0.1/Analytics.podspec`):

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name     = 'Analytics'
  s.version  = '0.0.1'
  s.platform = :ios
  s.summary  = "Analytics utility"
  s.homepage = 'http://apple.com'
  s.author   = { 'Dude' => 'dude@apple.com' }
  s.source   = { :git => 'https://github.com/Company/Analytics.git', :tag => '0.0.1' }
  s.source_files = 'Analytics/**/*.{h,m}'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.ios.deployment_target = '6.0'
end
```

Comment: I'm confused now. Are you trying to make a pod to distribute or use one in your project? A `Podfile` is for the ultimate consumers of your library. A `Podspec` is the file that determines how a library gets integrated with a project.

Comment: Sorry, I should've stated that we were trying to have our own private Specs repo, to manage private libraries

Comment: I see a few problems here. 1. You should only have **one** declaration of a workspace *or* xcodeproj in your Podfile. 2. Does this private spec repo contain specs for each of the components? I do not see them listed. 3. I think you are confusing a Podfile with a Podspec. You want to make Podspecs, not Podfiles.

Comment: We have created a Podspec for each module we want to use in our SDK (Analytics being one of them). This is the Podfile we were using on our main SDK project, we'll try with only one declaration of the workspace/project...

Comment: We'd like to use the existing workspace, that's why we specify the workspace and the project, otherwise it'll create a new workspace. The errors we get are `can't locate file for: -lPods-MySDK`,  `-lPods-MySDK is not an object file (not allowed in a library)` Any ideas?

Comment: Can you update your question with the new Podfile?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47973/discussion-between-eric-and-mishiemoo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [subspecs](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#subspec) that have [dependencies](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency) in CocoaPods. This allows you to define different pieces of code to be reused within different configurations.

If you're looking for a more robust example, checkout the [AFNetworking podspec](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking.podspec).

---

**Edit:** After some discussion in the chat, it turns out that the pod was not being integrated correctly with the project file. When this happens, remove `Pods`, and make sure the Pods.xcodeproj is being integrated with the correct project.

There also might be a bug in CP that involves integrating in a folder with multiple projects. I'll update this post with an Issue if that's true.

Comment: that would work, except that we want to have the different components in different git repositories

Comment: Then you need separate specs in each repository, and then one spec that does all the configuration. You still might want subspecs for that one.

Comment: I tried to do that, but Cocoapods couldn't link one library to another... I think you can't do it unless you manually lipo all the libraries together, is this right?

Comment: You can specify dependencies on other pods, but those pods need to also be in a specs repo (known issue). Can you update your question with the ideal repo/spec configuration you'd like to use?

Comment: Done! I also added the Podfile we were trying to use.